# Help picking/distinguishing these two algebra courses

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have the option of taking one or both of these classes, but I am unfamiliar with algebra and don't know the difference between the following two courses based on their descriptions:

MATH 578. Algebraic Structures. 3 Credits. (NOTE: taught by a very well regarded professor)
Permutation groups, matrix groups, groups of linear transformations, symmetry groups; finite abelian groups. Residue class rings, algebra of matrices, linear maps, and polynomials. Real and complex numbers, rational functions, quadratic fields, finite fields. (prerequisite is linear algebra/textbook is "First Course in Abstract Algebra" by Fraliegh)

MATH 534. Elements of Modern Algebra. 3 Credits. (NOTE: taught by a professor with mixed reviews)
Binary operations, groups, subgroups, cosets, quotient groups, rings, polynomials. (prerequisite is discrete math/intro to proofs/textbook is "Abstract Algebra" by Beachy)

What course would you rather take/what course would you think is more useful and a better introduction into the world of algebra? Or would taking them both be ideal?
Thank you so much!

Comment: I included the names of the books in parenthesis after their description. For the first course we use Fraleigh's "First Course in Abstract Algebra" and for the second course the textbook is "Abstract Algebra" by Beachy. I have no exposure to abstract algebra, it'll be my first pure math course (excluding the entry level proof course I took).

Comment: Are you a graduate student that needs to quickly catch up to graduate algebra, or an undergraduate? I'm familiar with Fraleigh's book and just looked at the table of contents (via amazon) of Beachy's book, and frankly I can't tell why there would be different numbered courses simultaneously offered using these books. It's quite possible that the difference in the courses has to do with how deeply the texts are covered and/or supplemented, and if so, unless you give the university (which you may not wish to do) *and* someone here is familiar with their courses, we may not be able to help much.

Comment: It also depends on whether you plan on going to graduate school, and how well you've adapted to any previous proof-based courses. I will say that for someone who has never had any abstract algebra before, Fraleigh's book is a very gentle introduction that gives a lot of explanatory motivation to the student.

Comment: I am currently an undergraduate. I will be taking this course next semester, during my sophomore year at UNC Chapel Hill. I thought they sounded awfully similar, I just don't know enough about the subject to be able to differentiate which one would be a better introduction to the subject.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I do plan on going to graduate school for math, but thus far have only taken applied math courses (calc1-3, linear, ode's, numerical techniques, and a course about Laplace and Fourier, very soft intro to PDEs and complex analysis)

Comment: I was an undergraduate there, and when I was there (late 1970s) there were two undergraduate level algebra courses (except I think they were numbered 34 and 38 (maybe 78), with the lower numbered course being primarily designed for math education majors and others not planning on attending graduate school. I think if you're a sophmore (2nd year for non-U.S. readers) planning to take abstract algebra, then you should definitely plan on taking the more advanced course. In fact, I'd go so far as to say that if you're not capable of easily handling the more advanced course, then **(continued)**

Comment: you probably shouldn't even be taking an abstract algebra course as a sophomore. I think when I was there this was typically done by 2 or 3 sophomores a year, these nearly always being top 100 Putnam and top 5 graduate program types, but with so many high school students getting college credit (even past calculus) today, maybe things have changed.

Comment: Understood. I just wanted to have some exposure to the subject as I think it will be very fascinating and have heard wonderful things. Also, from what I have heard, it is not as rigorous as real analysis so I wanted to develop a better understanding of formal logic and what not before taking real analysis. Thank you for your help again! I am definitely leaning towards the higher level course, especially since you recommend the textbook.

Comment: A book you might want to read over during Christmas break is [**A Concrete Approach to Abstract Algebra**](https://archive.org/details/AConcreteApproachToAbstractAlgebra) by W. W. Sawyer. I've known of this book for many years (by name only) and recently saw and purchased a copy at a used bookstore. The book seems to be absolutely wonderfully written, and in fact I plan on this being my "plane flight and hotel reading" for a work-related trip I'll be taking to India at the end of January. Derbyshire's **Unknown Quantity** was what I read on my last trip (that one only to another state).

Answer (score 1):

I would take $578$ unless the other one is prerequisite for it in which case I take both.

$578$ sounds like a real solid higher algebra course which jumps into concepts right away and covers many important topics.